# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to create a foreign key in which whenever I delete an intercambios, the comentarios that are linked to the intercambios get deleted too, here are my tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `intercambios` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `id_us` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `id_mec` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `mensaje` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
      `archivos` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
      `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `archivos_reducidos` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=176 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish_ci;
insert  into `intercambios`(`id`,`id_us`,`id_mec`,`mensaje`,`archivos`,`date`,`archivos_reducidos`) values (1,5,NULL,'usua','','2015-02-18 16:54:48',''),(2,0,9,'mec','','2015-02-18 16:59:59',''),(123,1,NULL,'d','','2015-02-25 14:40:33',''),(158,15,NULL,'Publicare','','2015-02-25 15:58:52',''),(159,NULL,12,'fgfdgfdgfd','','2015-02-25 17:35:47',''),(160,15,NULL,'','','2015-02-27 14:07:10',''),(161,15,NULL,'fdf','','2015-02-27 14:07:11',''),(163,15,NULL,'','../usuarios/Img_intercambios/imagen.jpg','2015-02-27 14:09:47',''),(166,NULL,12,'ee','','2015-02-27 15:15:38',''),(167,5,NULL,'mensaje de marc','','2015-02-27 16:39:41',''),(175,15,NULL,'Holis','','2015-03-04 16:43:50','');

    CREATE TABLE `comentarios_intercamb` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `id_intercambios` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_us` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `id_mec` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `comentario` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
      `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish_ci;
insert  into `comentarios_intercamb`(`id`,`id_intercambios`,`id_us`,`id_mec`,`comentario`,`date`) values (1,174,15,NULL,'Se ve?','2015-03-03 17:15:32'),(2,167,NULL,12,'EEE','2015-03-03 16:42:46'),(3,166,5,NULL,'ES EL BUENO','2015-03-03 16:42:52'),(4,174,15,NULL,'SIII','2015-03-03 17:27:31');
```

This is the error that I get when I try to save the foreign key.

```
Executed SQL Statement : Alter table `driveservice`.`comentarios_intercamb`  
  add foreign key (`id_intercambios`) references `driveservice`.`intercambios`(`id`) on update Cascade on delete Cascade 
Error Number : 1452 
Error Message: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`driveservice`.`#sql-2bc_c`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-2bc_c_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_intercambios`) REFERENCES `intercambios` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Obviously the name of the database is driveservice and I am using the Delete on Cascade property, but for some reason it doesn't works. I have seen plenty of examples on the internet and most of them were structured in the way that I am doing it.

Comment: Starting from a blank schema, creating the two tables and adding the foreign key constraint all works for me. Do you have any data already in your tables? If you do and it doesn't meet the conditions MySQL won't add the constraint.

Comment: Yeah, I already have some data on it, and indeed some of the data that I have included in both tables match (on the id_intercambios and the id of the intercambios table), so what would be the problem?

Comment: I'd guess that you have one or more rows in `comentarios_intercamb` with values in `id_intercambios` that do not appear in `intercambios.id`

Comment: @HoboSapiens you were right, I have values in `id_intercambios` that do not appear in  `intercambios.id`, thanks a lot man!.